# python tuple division

Tags: python, tuples

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

I'm getting above error , while I fetched a record  using query "select max(rowid) from table"
and assigned it to variable and while performing / operation is throws above message.
How to resolve this.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you're trying to do... What is the code that gives you the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql query `select max(rowid)` would return Tuple data like `records=(1000,)`

You may need to do like `numerator / records[0]`

Comment: thanks Mark, Now it's resolved.
@Wich,okay from next post I will be much more clearer in asking questions - I should have pasted the code part . :)